# Python Actor model + async (?)

Tags: python, asynchronous, actor

I'm currently thinking about writing an app in Python. My idea is creating multiple 'virtual' clients in the app that send data over MQTT, which is then received and processed. I was considering using the actor model for this, as my idea is the following:

New sender 'actor' created in app -> Sender creates receiver 'actor' for himself -> Sender connects to MQTT server -> Receiver listens on the server -> Sender and receiver are added to the event loop

I'm not sure if my reasoning is correct and if this is a good approach to what I want to do. I was looking for some feedback on what to change/improve in my idea.

All comments and suggestions are welcome. Many thanks!